# Halting a playing sound sample on iPhone using AudioServices

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, audio, core-audio

I am implementing a sound effect that plays while a user is dragging a UISlider.

Here is the IBAction: called by the UISlider's **Value Changed** event

```
-(IBAction)playTone4; {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID4); 
}
```

I would like the sound to halt when the user is **not** dragging the slider but has **not released** it.

Is there a way to do that? There doesn't seem to be an AudioServices**Stop**SystemSound() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**System sounds cannot be stopped**.

See the [**iPhone Programming Guide: section Multimeda Support**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW35) for more information.

To accomplish the desired effect, I would recommend using **AVAudioPlayer** or **audioQueues**. The Programming Guide I addressed covers everything you want to know about these techniques.